# Sharing the Wi-Fi Password with Both iOS and macOS devices Under the Same Apple ID?

Tags: macos, ios, network, wifi, password

Sharing the Wi-Fi Password with both iOS and macOS devices under the Same Apple ID is not available for me. I can share the the Wi-Fi password with other person if we if we are registered in the phone book both. However, I can't share my Wi-Fi password from my iMac to iPhone if I open both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.
I opened the Wi-Fi password type screen on iOS, hence a pop-up don't pop-up on Mac for allowance.

What is the main reason ?

iOS 12.1.4 & macOS 10.14.3

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Can you please clarify what **exactly** is the problem you're facing?

Comment: My question is about WiFi Password Sharing run schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiFi Password Sharing is only available if the password recieving device has the password sharing device in the contacts.app.

> Make sure your Apple ID is added to the other person's Contacts app.

- https://support.apple.com/HT209368

Comment: Hi @Daniil Manokhin. I'm registered in contacts.app with "Me" contact (Apple ID entered). Doesn't it work for me? I remember because I used to.